# Stopping the - (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController from being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios9, uisearchcontroller

I have a UISearchController and it implements the following method:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
```

This all works great but when I select a table cell and push to the new view controller via the self.navigationController and hit back, the updateSearch method above runs again.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: before pushing back set the delegate of searchcontroller as nil

Comment: how is that done if I push to a new view controller?

Comment: set delegate to nil on viewWillDisappear method.

Comment: oh not in the pushed vc but in the seach results vc

Comment: that was d'oh and simple thanks